# How to align this chemfig equation?

Tags: equations, alignment, chemfig, chemistry

I'm new to chemfig and I've tried every solution available on the internet for it. But nothing is working for me.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,chemfig}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preparation of Haloalkanes}

\section{From Alkanes (by direct halogination)}
\schemestart
\chemfig{R-[0]H} \+ \chemfig{X-[0]X} \arrow{->[h$\nu$][]}[,2,thick] \chemfig{R-[0]X} \+ \chemfig{HX}
\schemestop

\section{From Alkenes}

\subsection{By Addition of Hydrogen Halides}
\schemestart
\chemfig{C(-[:150])(-[:210])=C(-[:30])(-[:-30])} \+ \chemfig{H-X} \arrow{->[$\text{CCl}_4$][$\Delta$]}[,2,thick] \chemfig{C(-[:150])(-[:210])(-[:90]H)=C(-[:90]X)(-[:-30])(-[:30])}
\schemestop

\subsection{Addition of HX in symmetrical Alkene}
\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_2=[:0]CH_2} \+ \chemfig{HCl} \arrow{->[$\text{CCl}_4$][$\Delta$]}[,2,thick] \chemfig{CH_3-[:0]CH_2-[:0]Cl}
\schemestop

\subsection{Addition of HX in unsymmetrical Alkene}
\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_2=[:0]CH-[:0]CH_3} \+ \chemfig{HCl} \arrow{->[$\text{CCl}_4$][$\Delta$]}[,2,thick] \chemfig{CH_3-[:0]CH(-[:90]Cl)-[:0]CH_3}
\schemestop 
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `(.mid east--.mid west)` after the command `\arrow`

`\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[$\text{CCl}_4$][$\Delta$]}[,2,thick]`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can adjust the vertical position of the molecule using `\arrow(--shift=<number>pt){->}` ,number can be positive or negative.

Other commands to adjust the position only use a few fixed positions. With "yshift" it is possible to adjust the position more freely.

```
\subsection{By Addition of Hydrogen Halides}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{C(-[:150])(-[:210])=C(-[:30])(-[:-30])} \+ \chemfig{H-X} \arrow(--[yshift=12pt]){->[$\text{CCl}_4$][$\Delta$]}[,2,thick] \chemfig{C(-[:150])(-[:210])(-[:90]H)=C(-[:90]X)(-[:-30])(-[:30])}
    \schemestop
    
    \subsection{Addition of HX in symmetrical Alkene}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{CH_2=[:0]CH_2} \+ \chemfig{HCl} \arrow{->[$\text{CCl}_4$][$\Delta$]}[,2,thick] \chemfig{CH_3-[:0]CH_2-[:0]Cl}
    \schemestop
    
    \subsection{Addition of HX in unsymmetrical Alkene}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{CH_2=[:0]CH-[:0]CH_3} \+ \chemfig{HCl} \arrow(--[yshift=16pt]){->[$\text{CCl}_4$][$\Delta$]}[,2,thick] \chemfig{CH_3-[:0]CH(-[:90]Cl)-[:0]CH_3}
    \schemestop
```

[image]